# Apply formatting to headers with value and skip blank headers

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to format the header rows and skip the headers with blanks. I think I am getting close to the answer but I am having trouble to skip blank headers in vba codes. Here is what I have so far.
Is there a way to only format the headers that are not blanks?
Thank you

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim rowcount As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim rng2 As Range

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

rowcount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A6", Range("A6").End(xlDown)))
Set rng = ws.Range("A6")
rng.CurrentRegion.Select
Set rng2 = Range("A6:E6")

` Here is the part I am not quite sure how to write`

If Not IsEmpty(rng2) Then
    For i = 6 To rowcount
    
     Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    
    Next i

End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Are you able to just use conditional formatting to apply the formatting you need, without responding to VBA?

Comment: This might get tricky because I also need to format all the rows depending on the updates received each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `For Each` loop

```
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In rng2
        If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
            ' your code
        End If
    Next c
```

The code could be simplified.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lstRow As Long
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lstRow = ws.Range("A6").End(xlDown).Row
    For Each rng2 In ws.Range("A6:E6")
        If Not IsEmpty(rng2) Then
            With rng2.Resize(lstRow - rng2.Row + 1, 1).Borders
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
        End If
    Next rng2
End Sub
```

Microsoft reference document:

> [XlBordersIndex enumeration (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlbordersindex?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Borders object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.borders?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)